# Custom Search for Umbraco Backoffice List View

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7

I have created a document type which uses a List View to show its children. The children are another document type, representing Posts with title,date , etc.

The List View provides a 'Search' field, however I would like to implement some additional filters, like search by date , or a drop-down list based on the my date of my posts in one of the columns.

Is this possible in a standard Umbraco implementation? Thanks!

Comment: This kind of thing generally requires a custom plugin - you can base it off the List View code in the Umbraco project, but you'll need to implement your own services to retrieve the results based on your required filtering.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how I can male the custom plugin in List View. Can you help me or give me Url tutorial for this

Comment: Review the documentation: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Tutorials/Creating-a-Property-Editor/ also you can use this project as a basis (it's not new, and is targeted a Membership but you should be able to pull some ideas from it): https://github.com/KOBENDigital/umbMemberListView